# how do i add multiple columns to a listbox using mixed data types in vba?

Tags: listbox, ms-access-2010, multiple-columns

I'm trying to add items (multiple columns) to a listbox. As I understand, in order to add multiple columns, you normally send them as strings like so:

```
Listbox.AddItem("column1;column2;column3")
```

This works for me just fine. But how do I add multiple columns when the item is not a string? I've tried things like:

```
Listbox.AddItem("name"; txtAge.Value)
```

and

```
Listbox.AddItem("name; txtAge.Value")
```

and even

```
Listbox.AddItem("name; Me![txtAge]")
```

None are working. I wasn't able to find anything on the web. What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to cast the txtAge to a String....

```
    LTrim(str(txtAge.value))
```

or

```
    CStr(txtAge.value)
```

Comment: this didn't work for me. Im getting an error on the separator ; maybe my format is wrong. Could you give an example of a full additem line?

Comment: Listbox.AddItem("name"; CStr(txtAge.value))

Comment: Got it. it's actually "name;" & CStr(txtAge.value)   --- really the object was to get the argument to read as a single string that includes the semicolon(;) for each separator.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, just a little edit though:

Listbox.AddItem("name; " & txtAge.Value)